# Streaming personal music collection over the internet

Tags: windows, internet, streaming, music

Is there a way I can stream my personal music collection over the internet. I have a always on, always connected PC running Windows 7 which hosts the music collection. On my home network, streaming it from the PC to Xbox is trivial. Is there a way to do over the internet so that I have access to it, say, at the place I work?

Comment: did you try any of these ones I suggested? did it work well for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Audiogalaxy](http://www.audiogalaxy.com)** is drop-dead simple, and just works!

> "Audiogalaxy's new cloud music player puts all your music and playlists at your fingertips from any computer or mobile phone. Audiogalaxy Mobile for iPhone Audiogalaxy for Android
>   No syncing, no copying, no uploading.
>   Just streaming.

http://lifehacker.com/5616663/audiogalaxy-makes-streaming-music-from-your-pc-dead-simple

Comment: Looks like audiogalaxy no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp). I can even browse and listen to my collection on my Android phone. Here is the [demo page](http://subsonic.org/demo/login.view?user=guest4&password=guest). Works on multiple platforms too. Streaming to your work depends on which port you decide to use. I would see if your ISP allows port 80 outgoing traffic. If not, you can set up SSL (port 443) since most work places should allow that. By default, Subsonic uses port 4040 but you can change it.

[Community Support](http://forum.subsonic.org/) is great and the author continues to improve the product.

If you need to stream to your Xbox, try [PS3MediaServer](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/). Works on the Xbox as well.

Comment: This is the best cross platform solution I can find circa September 2014.

Answer (score 1):

try [shoutcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools), it's quite popular 
 
you can also try [vibe streamer](http://www.vibestreamer.com/)

you'll probably have to enable port forwarding on your router for the streaming to work.

Comment: vibe streamer website appears to be down. I'm not quite able to able to setup port forwarding for shoutcast.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is Orb (now called "Orb Classic"). It is super easy to install and doesn't require any port forwarding, remembering your IP address, etc.

You can stream your music, photos, videos and even live TV using it. You access your content via the web. Get it at http://corp.orb.com/en/download_orb

Comment: in my experience, Orb has had trouble running on my Vista system, back when I had it...

Comment: @studiohack this is a win7 system and may not apply... i've used this on my win7 and it appears to work fine.

Comment: It works fine on my Vista system.

Answer (score 1):

You already have it installed:  [**Windows Media Player 12**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/e7/media-streaming-with-windows-7).

Comment: This is a great link. Unfortunately, I use XP at work so I'm stuck with WMP9 for now. Any idea if this'll work if I upgrade to WMP11 ?

Comment: @pulkitsinha: Yes, WMP11 supports DLNA, so you should be able to stream to it from WMP12.